# Check if string is in date format (UNIX)?

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

I would like to check if that variable is in the correct date format or the variable is empty... if it is in the correct date format then i will perform sth

I have tried:

```
dada=2015-10-11
if [[ "$dada" = ^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$ ]]
  then echo "Date $dada is valid  (YYYY-MM-DD)"

  else echo "Date $dada is not invalid format (YYYY-MM-DD)"
fi
```

And also

```
 if [ "`date '+%Y-%m-%d' -d $d 2>/dev/null`" = "$dada" ]

    then echo "Date $dada is valid  (YYYY-MM-DD)"

  else echo "Date $dada is not invalid format (YYYY-MM-DD)"
fi
```

But it seems like it will always return and telling me that my format is incorrect.

$dada is a dynamic variable wherby it can be a number '444.1' , date format '2017-11-12' or a string 'hello this is not valid'

Comment: How thorough a check do you want?  Should the check reject `2015-02-29`, for example?  The classic way would be `case "$dada" in ([12][0189][0-9][0-9]-[01][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]) : OK;; (*) : Not OK;; esac` — but there are probably better modern ways of doing it.  That mainly allows 18xy, 19xy, 20xy, 21xy (though it does let through 10xy, 11xy, 28xy, 29xy) as years; you'll have to decide whether that's sensible.  Similarly, it lets through months 13-19, and days 32-39; those are unconditionally invalid.  Then you're left with "30 days hath September, …" to worry about.

Comment: 2015-02-29 should be also rejected yup! @JonathanLeffler

Comment: If you need to reject `2015-02-29`, you're going to need much more checking than a single line — or the single line will be very long and complex and will have many alternatives in it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler i see i see, how about just checking if the string format is in place like XXXX-XX-XX? the current code that i have is returning me the "invalid echo"

Comment: The `case` command I showed does a reasonable job for years in the range 1800 through 2199.  But it is 'old school' notation.  The merit is it works and I don't have to read the manual.  Test it — change the `:` commands into `echo`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I have tried the case but it seems like the code did not identify my dada as date. Is there any problem with my declaration on dada?

Comment: On my Mac, I was able to run (verbatim — a single line command): `ksh -c 'dada=2015-10-11; case "$dada" in ([12][0189][0-9][0-9]-[01][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]) echo OK;; (*) echo Not OK;; esac'` and I got `OK` as the output.  For values such as `2215-10-11` and `2015-20-11`, I got `Not OK`.  What were you doing?  It would be better, but isn't actually crucial, to use `dada="2015-01-11";` instead of the unquoted form.  So, how did you test it?

Comment: Hello @JonathanLeffler, May i know what is for? [12][0189][0-9][0-9]

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks !! :)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Hello, may i know how about if i were to add a time at the back of the date etc 2015-20-11 23:21 , if i can write is as 'case "$HELLO" in ([0-3][0-9]/[01][0-9]/[0-9][0-9] [0-2][0-9]:[0-6][0-9])'

Comment: You could certainly add a glob expression that would match the time.  I'm not sure I understand why the one you propose might be correct, but other patterns could be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sup>*Converting an extensive set of comments into an answer.*</sup>

How thorough a check do you want? Should the check reject 2015-02-29, for example?

> 2015-02-29 should be also rejected yup!

If you need to reject `2015-02-29`, you're going to need much more checking than a single line — or the single line will be very long and complex and will have many alternatives in it.

---

The classic way to validate the data pattern would use the pattern matching from the `case` statement — maybe using something like this:

```
case "$dada" in
([12][0189][0-9][0-9]-[01][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]) : OK;;
(*) : Not OK;;
esac
```

but there are probably better modern ways of doing it. That mainly allows years 18xy, 19xy, 20xy, 21xy (though it does also let through 10xy, 11xy, 28xy, 29xy); you'll have to decide whether that's sensible. Similarly, it lets through months 13-19 (and `00`), and days 32-39 (and `00`); those are unconditionally invalid. Then you're left with "[30 days hath September, …](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thirty_Days_Hath_September)" to worry about.

If you removed the leading `(` around the patterns, that statement would work in antique and archaic shells such as the Bourne shell.  It isn't tied to Korn shell — it is standard notation in POSIX-like shells, and pre-POSIX shells.

> How about just checking if the string format is in place like XXXX-XX-XX?

The case command I showed does a reasonable job for years in the range 1800 through 2199. But it is 'old school' notation. The merit is it works and I don't have to read the manual. Test it — change the `:` commands into `echo`.

> I have tried the case but it seems like the code did not identify my data as a date. Is there any problem with my declaration of `dada`?

On my Mac, I was able to run (verbatim — a single line command):

```
ksh -c 'dada=2015-10-11; case "$dada" in ([12][0189][0-9][0-9]-[01][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]) echo OK;; (*) echo Not OK;; esac'
```

and I got `OK` as the output. For values such as `2215-10-11` and `2015-20-11`, I got `Not OK`.  It would be better, but isn't actually crucial, to use `dada="2015-01-11";` instead of the unquoted form.

> How about if I were to add a time at the back of the date — `2015-20-11 23:21`?  Can I write it as '`case "$HELLO" in ([0-3][0-9]/[01][0-9]/[0-9][0-9] [0-2][0-9]:[0-6][0-9])'`

You could certainly add a glob expression that would match the time. I don't understand why the one you propose might be correct, but other patterns could be used.

For example:

```
dada="2015-11-20 23:21"
case "$dada" in
([12][0189][0-9][0-9]-[01][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]\ [012][0-9]:[0-5][0-9])
    echo OK;;
(*) echo Not OK;;
esac
```

Note that the backslash is needed before the space in the pattern.  When run with the data shown, the script reports `OK`.  Change `23` to `32` and it reports `Not OK`.

There probably is a way to do this with the `[[` command instead of writing out the `case` statement.

Doing more complex (thorough) validation using `case` is probably not a good idea.  You'd do better to invoke a tool that validates dates properly.  You might be able to use the (GNU) `date` command, or you could use Perl or Python or one of those scripting languages.  These would reject `2015-02-29 23:21` but allow `2016-02-29 23:21` without problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
dada=2015-10-11
date -d $dada > /dev/null 2>&1 
[[ $? -eq 0 ]] && echo ok  ||  echo not ok
```